# how to take a screen shot on a button click can anyone provide a android code

Tags: android

I want to take the screen shot of current screen when,I click a button.Can anyone provide a android code.I need to save the image in the gallery also.this is what i tried

```
public class CaptureScreenShots extends Activity {
LinearLayout L1;
ImageView image;
 @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_shots);
    L1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.munchscreen);
    but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View v1 = L1.getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.screenshots);
            image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.screen_shots, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "can I haz teh code?" questions are off-topic. Please show us what you have done.

Comment: similar ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Comment: public class CaptureScreenShots extends Activity {
    LinearLayout L1;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen_shots);
        L1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
        Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.munchscreen);
        but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

Comment: @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View v1 = L1.getRootView();
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.screenshots);
                image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: i am a beginner,sorry for my mistake @Little Child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 private void getScreen(){
            View v = view.getRootView();
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
            String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myPath = new File(extr, getString(R.string.free_tiket)+".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage( getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: does it automatically save the photo to our memory

Comment: No. You have to implement to manually. First create a folder through programatically and then specify path where you want to store your pic.

Comment: Either you can save path in Any location in you mobile and  when you need that image call image path and change image path to Bitmap and apply to imageView

Comment: This captures the status bar as white

Answer (score 5):

set button click listener

```
share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
        saveBitmap(bitmap);

    }
});
```

then you have to create two method

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
}
}
```

After add this code into your app, run the app and check your local storage, you have created screen shot of whole page.

Comment: simple and concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your code,when i am click the button image will stored as black screen because i developed with surfaceview custom camera...What will do complete image save in local storage.