# if i take screenshot, the screen shot image show in my activity.how to hide it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

i created screenshot for my activity in programatically.it work perfectly.i have problem in after taking shot the image showing in my activity.how to hide it?

Mycode :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    File cacheDir;
    final Context context = this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button print = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_print);

        print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takeScreenShot();
            }
        });



    }

       private void takeScreenShot() {

        View u =  findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        int spec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        u.measure(spec, spec);
        u.layout(0, 0, u.getMeasuredWidth(), u.getMeasuredHeight());

        Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(u,u.getMeasuredHeight(),u.getMeasuredWidth());

        final String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        File myPath = new File(root + "/saved_img");
        myPath.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+n+".jpg";
        File file = new File(myPath, fname);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        if(file.exists()) file.delete();
        try{
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();


        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this,"screen captured",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View u, int totalHeight, int totalWidth){
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth,totalHeight , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);

        Drawable bgDrawable = u.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        u.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
}
```

how to solve this? my output image  for before click button,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt0ZY.png)

this is my output 2 for after click the button,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q51wG.png)

Comment: what u need to do? you want screenshot only? but not shown that in your activity right?

Comment: yes.correct.how to hide showing my screenshot image in activity...

Comment: don't use the getBitmapFromview then how to get activity height& width on whole activity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32624305/7320259 please try this bro. Hope it helps you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/7320259 and try this two. this both are similar. you have to take whole view like this View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

Comment: bro above link are "how to take screenshot".but my question are "after taking screenshot that image show in my activity.how to hide it?" this is my question bro.@ Zaki Pathan

Comment: If you need screenshot without title bar check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30212385/7320259

Comment: you have to try that code. because i test it this works fine in my activity. Please check your further code. this code works fine. I think some other code affect this. please check which code runs after this your functions call

Comment: @zaki pathan.. bro understand my question please.this code working perfectly.i know that.but i want to know "how to hide, screenshot image from activity?????"

Comment: you need to hide screenshot which is displaying after clicking button right? you dont need to close your activity right? while using your above code no screenshot is appear on screen. activity is there when i use your code. So some other code affects this and show you a screenshot on your screen. Hope you understand now?

Comment: check this link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/q51wG.png @Zaki pathan this is my final out put image

Comment: try using your device not emulator it helps you @Thiru

Comment: no it's not error bro.my need are after taking the screenshot, the image doesn't show in app screen.but it show.

Comment: sorry bro my poor english.what i m saying are,after button click the image show in my app.but my need are the image i don't want.then how to hide it?

Comment: So no need to set captured screenshot in image. Post your full code please. I dont understand properly what u asking for

Comment: bro.i explain my view of this program.i want to take screenshot for my current activity.i done it.unfortunately after getting screenshot the screenshoted view are here in my activity.but i don't want it.how can i avoid it

Comment: you have extra code in your activity? Because I tried your above code in my activity and thats work fine and no view of screenshot is visible in activity. So this code is perfect and working without viewing your captured screenshot in activity. Now you understand what i am telling?

Comment: yes.i understand what you saying.but in my side it will be appear.just a min i update my question with output images.just 2 mins

Comment: after clicking button the activity streatch itself.but functionality are work fine.but activity streatched.it's can't be solve???

Comment: you can try by using  View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(); full screen view not for your xml layout. Please check my links

Comment: bro before i use that method.but it not work in using scrollview in activity.but my above code work perfectly using scrollview also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's my mistake.after getting screenshot i set layout size on capturing image size(based on get measure width & height)i remove the below line in program it work perfectly.

**u.layout(0, 0, u.getMeasuredWidth(), u.getMeasuredHeight());**

because that line set saved image exact height & width into current layout.so that's error.i solved it.thanks for your help for all.thanks once again...